# How can i view a mapreduce job/hadoop output file

Tags: mapreduce, hdfs

I ran a mapreduce job on hadoop, and i am trying to view the output but it keeps printing this out on the command line. [image]

i used this command to try and view the job.

```
hdfs dfs -cat /books-result/part-r-00000 | head -n 20
```

Comment: You ran mapreduce or Spark? Please show the code that output that file (which is obviously binary, not plaintext)

Comment: try -text instead of -cat in case you use encoding

Answer (score 0):

Since the file is encoded, it cant be visualised by cat. You can convert any such encoding into plain text by using "text" command. You can use :
hdfs dfs -text /books-result/part-r-00000 | head -n 20
and it will do the work.